# React showing previous state ,only updates on refreshing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am developing an e-commerce application and on productdetail page my main image is showing previous state ..only updates on refreshing page

```js
const [mainImage, setMainImage] = useState(images[0])

return (
  <>
    <div className="product display-img-left">
      {(images.length > 1) && (
        images.map((image,index)=>(
          <img key={index} onClick={()=>setMainImage(image)} src={`http://localhost:3000/public/products/${image}`}/>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
    <div className="product display-main-img">
      <img src={`http://localhost:3000/public/products/${mainImage}`}/>
    </div>
  </>
)
```

Comment: Create a function that handles the onClick event triggered within the images.map() method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one to resolve the issue :

```
   const [mainImage, setMainImage] = useState(images[0]);
    
  
    useEffect(() => {
      setMainImage(images[0]); 
    }, [images]);
    
    return (
      <div className="productdisplay-img-left">
        {images.length > 1 &&
          images.map((image, index) => (
            <img
              key={index}
              onClick={() => setMainImage(image)}
              src={`http://localhost:3000/public/products/${image}`}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
      <div className="productdisplay-main-img">
        <img src={`http://localhost:3000/public/products/${mainImage}`} />
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided looks mostly correct, but it's likely a problem with the state not updating properly or the event handling of the click event. Create a function that call on onClick event in the images.map()

```
const ProductDetail = ({ images }) => {
  const [mainImage, setMainImage] = useState(images[0]);

  const handleImageClick = (image) => {
    setMainImage(image);
  };

  return (
    <div className="productdisplay-img-left">
      {images.length > 1 &&
        images.map((image, index) => (
          <img
            key={index}
            onClick={() => handleImageClick(image)}
            src={`http://localhost:3000/public/products/${image}`}
            alt={`Product ${index}`}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
    <div className="productdisplay-main-img">
      <img src={`http://localhost:3000/public/products/${mainImage}`} alt="Main Product" />
    </div>
  );
};
```